# Small pause in android app before taking next input from user

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically I need a pause (based on just a few seconds) to be put into one action so that the user can see what happens before the next action is taken.
i have tried using posteDelayed method of the handler class but on creating the object of Handler class i am getting an error in the conctructor call.
it says 'Handler' is abstract;cannot be instantiated.the code for the activity in which i am using handler is

```html
public class Game extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    int genno,pos,exact;
    boolean flag;
    float balrem,betamt,multiplier;
    Spinner spin;
    TextView rembal;
    TextView bet_amount;
    TextView result;
    TextView beton;
    EditText bet;
    Button okgen;
    private Handler mhandler = new Handler();
    String options[]={"ODD NUMBER","EVEN NUMBER","PRIME NUMBER","MULTIPLE OF 3","EXACT NUMBER" };
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder;
    public Game (){
        multiplier=1;
        flag=false;
    }
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        rembal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        bet_amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        beton=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        bet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        okgen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_option=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
        adapter_option.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter_option);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int userno = extras.getInt("gotcha");
        rembal.setText("REMAINING BALANCE   : "+ " " +userno);
        //rembal.setText("Remaining Balance : " + userno);
        balrem=(float)userno;
        //here balrem is balance with which user entered it is different once we go inside onclick listener as it changes and will become zero

        okgen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //result.setText("result now brother="+ userno);


                //            rembal.setText("Remaining Balance  : " + balrem);

                if(balrem>0){
                    // inpbet=bet.getText().toString();
                    String inpbet=bet.getText().toString();
                    if(inpbet.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Need To Choose An Amount For The Bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        betamt= Float.parseFloat(inpbet);

                        if(betamt==balrem){
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Dude!!You Are All In..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if(betamt>balrem){
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Seriously!!Who Let You Inside The Casino",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(betamt==0){
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Let's Make A Deal : #I_Play_IF_You_Play# ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            balrem=balrem-betamt;
                            Random r= new Random();
                            genno=(((((r.nextInt(100)%69)+31)%10)%8)+1);
                            pos=spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            if(pos==0){
                                //odd number bet
                                if(genno%2==1){
                                    flag=true;
                                    multiplier= (float) 1.1;
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Won 10% of your bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else if(pos==1){
                                //even number bet
                                if(genno%2==0){
                                    flag=true;
                                    multiplier= (float) 1.1;
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Won 10% of your bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                            else if(pos==2){
                                //prime number bet
                                if(genno==2||genno==3||genno==5||genno==7){
                                    flag=true;
                                    multiplier= (float) 1.25;
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Won 25% of your bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else if(pos==3){
                                //multiple of 3 bet
                                if(genno==3||genno==6||genno==9){
                                    flag=true;
                                    multiplier= (float) 1.5;
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Won 50% of your bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else if(pos==4){
                                //exact bet
                                //alert input
                                if(genno==exact){
                                    flag=true;
                                    multiplier=2;
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Won 100% of your bet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }

                        }
                        if(flag==true){
                            balrem+=(betamt*multiplier);
                            result.setText("You Won!!Generated Number Is : "+genno);
                            if(balrem>100000){
                                balrem=99999;
                                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Sorry Bro!!Can't let you have more than 100000(Silly Casino Policies) ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            rembal.setText("REMAINING BALANCE   : "+ " " +Math.floor(balrem));
                            flag=false;
                        }
                        else{

                            result.setText("You lost../:-( Generated Number Is : "+genno);
                            rembal.setText("REMAINING BALANCE   : "+ " " +Math.floor(balrem));
                        }

                    }

                }
                if(balrem<1){
                    //alert box for game ower button to goto play activity again
                    result.setText("game is over");
                    gameoverdialog();
                }
                if((pos==4) && (balrem>=1) && (balrem>=betamt)){
                    //pause here i want to pause the app before calling exactalertbox method

                    mhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            exactalertbox();
                        }
                    }, 1000);


                }
            }
```

Comment: post code and error logs, it's impossible to tell what's wrong if not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you got the error but this is how you create it:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              //doStuff OR leaveEmpty
         } 
    }, 2000);
```

`2000` is the delay (in milliseconds). Change it to what you like.

**EDIT:** Also, make sure you imported the Correct Handler class:

```
import android.os.Handler; //Correct class
import java.util.logging.Handler; //Wrong class. Remove it
```

Comment: Still have the same problem

Comment: Where are you using it? Edit your question with the full code and log error.

Comment: @rishabh Did you check the imports?

Comment: yeah its fine now thanks!!
sorry for replying so late